# C#, Iterating over a common parent class for generic children

Tags: c#, class, generics, foreach, ienumerable

How would I setup the following classes so that I could have a method that takes a common parent class/interface and allow me to iterate over any child without specifying the generic Type?

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{ ??? }

public class ChildClass<T> : BaseClass 
{
    public List<T> SomeList;
            ???
}

ChildClass<int> childA = new ChildClass<int> ();
ChildClass<string> childB = new ChildClass<string> ();

public void IterateOverChild (BaseClass someChildClass)
{
    foreach (var element in someChildClass.SomeList)    
    {
        Console.WriteLine (element);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can't with normal ways

Comment: BaseClass is unaware of any properties that exist on ChildClass. Why not make BaseClass generic? In other words -- it looks like you could better abstract what you're wanting to do.

Comment: The problem with a generic BaseClass is that you can't refer to it in code without the generic. For example, you'd have to have `void IterateOverChild<T>(BaseClass<T> someChildClass)`. There are lots of situations where you need a non-generic base class because the generic type isn't available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have the abstract class expose some means of accessing the data that is common between the child classes, in this case, a sequence of data where each object can be of any type:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract IEnumerable Data { get; }
}

public class ChildClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    public List<T> SomeList { get; set; }
    public override IEnumerable Data { get { return SomeList; } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public List<T> SomeList { get; set; }

}

public class ChildClass<T> : BaseClass<T>
{

}

public void IterateOverChild<T>(BaseClass<T> someChildClass)
{
    foreach (var element in someChildClass.SomeList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily an option.  Imagine, for example, that he would want to have a `List<BaseClass>` in which each of those base classes were a different generic type.  That wouldn't be possible using your code.

Comment: If base class must be non generic then your answer works better

Answer (score 0):

Unless `BaseClass` knows about `<T>`, it cannot have any properties or methods of type `T`. However, you can provide a base implementation that at least exposes a non-generic form of your property. You lose type information but preserve enumerability.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public IList SomeList { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass<T> : BaseClass 
{
    public new List<T> SomeList
    {
        get { return (List<T>) base.SomeList; }
        set { base.SomeList = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than storing a narrowly scoped data structure in a broadly defined variable, which is error prone, it's better to have the broadly defined member be a view onto a more narrowly scoped storage location.